# Where can I get the "default" android arrow graphic for MapView?

Tags: android, maps, android-mapview

I am using a custom overlay on my MapView and I'm trying to imitate the look of the official Google "Maps" application when using the GPS and as a result I'm looking for the arrow the application uses to show your bearing.

*The closest I've found is [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_PiaX_YSoZGA/SujKmuV-uQI/AAAAAAAAAGA/7Zo8BhiBejA/s200/Google+Maps+Navigation.gif) but it's too large, its not an animated GIF like the official one and I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use it or not.*

**Edit: Just found out that is completely useless because I forgot (obviously) gifs do not have an alpha transparency layer.**

Has anyone had to use this before? Am I going to be forced to make my own?

Comment: I've had the exact same issue.  I'm not exactly sure why the google API wouldn't come with a pushpin icon, like the iPhone's map does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look in the MyTracks project: http://code.google.com/p/mytracks

Here are the bearing arrows: http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/browse/#hg/MyTracks/res/drawable
Are those what you are looking for?
(Click on a arrow, then Show raw file)

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but it will have to do I think, the search is becoming hopeless. I'm allowed to use there graphics as long as I credit them in my application somewhere aren't I?

Comment: The content is licensed under the following license: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which arrow you're looking for, however, if you look in your Android SDK folder and you've got 2.2 installed, platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable-mdpi\ contains compass_arrow.png and compass_base.png. Could those work?

Comment: Thanks but no dice. It's not the compass I'm looking for, otherwise I'd use MyLocationOverlay rather than extending Overlay. The one I'm looking for looks exactly like the one In my original post, but it's smaller and a transparent PNG. I have a bad feeling it's not offered freely by Google as it's part of the maps application, which is obviously separate from the android platform.